Flask app builder extend base model and add extra column to it
I want to know how I can extend flask app builder base models. Example I have User model in flask_appbuilder/security/sqla
class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = "ab_user"
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence("ab_user_id_seq"), primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    username = Column(String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(256))
    active = Column(Boolean)
    email = Column(String(320), unique=True, nullable=False)
    last_login = Column(DateTime)
    login_count = Column(Integer)
    fail_login_count = Column(Integer)
    roles = relationship("Role", secondary=assoc_user_role, backref="user")
    created_on = Column(
        DateTime, default=lambda: datetime.datetime.now(), nullable=True
    )
    changed_on = Column(
        DateTime, default=lambda: datetime.datetime.now(), nullable=True
    )

    @declared_attr
    def created_by_fk(self):
        return Column(
            Integer, ForeignKey("ab_user.id"), default=self.get_user_id, nullable=True
        )

    @declared_attr
    def changed_by_fk(self):
        return Column(
            Integer, ForeignKey("ab_user.id"), default=self.get_user_id, nullable=True
        )

    created_by = relationship(
        "User",
        backref=backref("created", uselist=True),
        remote_side=[id],
        primaryjoin="User.created_by_fk == User.id",
        uselist=False,
    )
    changed_by = relationship(
        "User",
        backref=backref("changed", uselist=True),
        remote_side=[id],
        primaryjoin="User.changed_by_fk == User.id",
        uselist=False,
    )

I have extended this model in my custom config file (superset_config.py) to add some extra column.
class CustomUser(User):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomUser, self).__init__()

    __tablename__ = "ab_user"
    channel_id = Column(Integer, server_default = '0', default='0')

so when I am runnning superset create admin I am getting this error
superset_config:Error adding new user to database. Attempting to flush an item of type <class 'superset_config.CustomRole'> as a member of collection "User.roles". Expected an object of type <class 'flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.models.Role'> or a polymorphic subclass of this type. If <class 'superset_config.CustomRole'> is a subclass of <class 'flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.models.Role'>, configure mapper "mapped class Role->ab_role" to load this subtype polymorphically, or set enable_typechecks=False to allow any subtype to be accepted for flush. in superset_config
This question is related to apache superset but this error is generic. I can understand that it is trying to add some data using superset_config.CustomRole but it needs flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.models.Role model. I want that it should work with CustomRole model also as all the properties are persent in this model
Can anyone suggest or help how can solve this issue. I just want to extend that model and keep same tablename and add channel_id extra property.
